# NHibernate bad performance with multiple insert request

Tags: c#, .net, performance, nhibernate

I'facing performance issue with my .net 5 website using nhibernate.

i have controller with action method used by application and also esposed as api calls

action simply insert a record ot this type

```
public class Ente : BaseObject<Ente, string>
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descrizione { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Perimetro { get; set; }
    public virtual int Ordine { get; set; }
}
```

where baseObject implements Equals methods

**performance issues raise when application receive multiple rest call: each insert take about 2 seconds**

i can receive hundreds consecutive calls and systeme take minutes to manage all

this is save method in repository:

```
protected ISession _session;
    public CrudlRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
    public virtual void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        _session.Save(entity);
    }
```

this is action method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(string values)
    {
        var obj = new Ente ();
        using (myUow = myUowFactory.Create())
        {
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, obj);
            myUow.Repository.Create(obj);
            myUow.SaveAll();
        }
        return Ok("Operazione completata con successo.");
    }
```

this is my configuration:

```
string connectionString = DbSettings.Current.ConnectionStrings.OracleWHB;

        services.AddSingleton<ISessionFactory>(sp => Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(OracleManagedDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                .ConnectionString(DbSettings.Current.ConnectionStrings.OracleWHB)
                .DoNot.ShowSql()
                .DoNot.FormatSql())
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<UnitOfWork>()
            )
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => SetupEnvers(config, sp))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, genereteDB))

            //https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/on-nhibernate-performance per dettagli
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.GenerateStatistics, Boolean.FalseString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Hbm2ddlKeyWords, Hbm2DDLKeyWords.None.ToString()))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.PrepareSql, Boolean.TrueString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.PropertyBytecodeProvider, "lcg"))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.PropertyUseReflectionOptimizer, Boolean.TrueString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.QueryStartupChecking, Boolean.FalseString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseProxyValidator, Boolean.FalseString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseSecondLevelCache, Boolean.FalseString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseSqlComments, Boolean.FalseString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseQueryCache, Boolean.FalseString))
            .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.WrapResultSets, Boolean.TrueString))

            .BuildSessionFactory()
        );
        services.AddScoped<ISession>(sp => sp.GetService<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
        services.AddTransient<IRevisionListener, EnversRevisionListener>();

        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWorkFactory, UnitOfWorkFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        return services;
```

base object

```
public abstract class BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> : EquatableObject<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    {
        public abstract TKey Id { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

            BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> other = obj as BaseObject<TEntity, TKey>;

            return BaseObjectEquals(other);

        }

        public override bool Equals(TEntity obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

            BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> other = obj as BaseObject<TEntity, TKey>;

            return BaseObjectEquals(other);

        }

        public virtual bool BaseObjectEquals(BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(this.Id , other.Id);
        }

        private IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields()
        {
            Type t = GetType();

            List<FieldInfo> fields = new List<FieldInfo>();
            while (t != typeof(object))
            {
                fields.AddRange(t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name));//.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public));

                t = t.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
            }
            return fields;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> x, BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> y)
        {
            // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
            if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If one is null, but not both, return false.
            if (((object)x == null) || ((object)y == null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> x, BaseObject<TEntity, TKey> y)
        {
            return !(x == y);
        }
    }
```

EquatableObject

```
public abstract class EquatableObject<TObject>: IEquatable<TObject>
    where TObject : class

{
    ///  < summary >
    /// Default Constructor.
    ///  < /summary >
    protected EquatableObject()
    {
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        Type t = GetType();

        TypeInfo typeInfo = t.GetTypeInfo();
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = typeInfo.DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name);

        int startValue = 17;
        int multiplier = 59;
        int hashCode = startValue;

        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            object value = field.GetValue(this);
            if (value != null)
                hashCode = hashCode * multiplier + value.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hashCode;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        TObject other = obj as TObject;

        return Equals(other);

    }

    public virtual bool Equals(TObject other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        Type t = GetType();

        TypeInfo typeInfo = t.GetTypeInfo();
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = typeInfo.DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name);
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            object value1 = field.GetValue(other);
            object value2 = field.GetValue(this);

            if (value1 == null)
            {
                if (value2 != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!value1.Equals(value2))
                return false;
        }
        return true;

    }


    public static bool operator ==(EquatableObject<TObject> x, EquatableObject<TObject> y)
    {
        // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if (((object)x == null) || ((object)y == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EquatableObject<TObject> x, EquatableObject<TObject> y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
}
```

and SaveAll in Repository

```
public void SaveAll()
    {
        if (_transaction != null)
        {
            _transaction.Commit();
            _transaction = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the issue is not on the db level, performance tuning can only be  done after measuring all the parts involved, but based on the code you showed:

If the version of nhibernate you are using supports async calls and you can use something like

```
await _transaction.CommitAsync();
```

Then you would, in any case, benefit from it in a concurrent scenario with long I/O calls like the one you described. If the db server is doing ok I would guess this is your main issue.

[async in depth on microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth)

> Throughout this entire process, a key takeaway is that no thread is dedicated to running the task. Although work is executed in some context (that is, the OS does have to pass data to a device driver and respond to an interrupt), there is no thread dedicated to waiting for data from the request to come back. This allows the system to handle a much larger volume of work rather than waiting for some I/O call to finish.

To avoid being forced to change all methods to async add an async version of SaveAll() e.g. SaveAllAsync(), this would require to change to async only the method in this controller. The overall benefits would be less than a complete change but you could at least test and see if it is a good road.

On the other hand, in your equatable object, you can cache the enumeration of the reflection somewhere so you would not need to perform this every time:

```
    Type t = GetType();
    TypeInfo typeInfo = t.GetTypeInfo();
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = typeInfo.DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name);
```

Comment: reflection of EquatableObject is used only by value object: standard one's uses GetHashCode of BaseObject that read only the Id. performance issues was on standard object. but i get the point and change that will be in plan

Comment: using async is more complex since all calling methods should become async....

Comment: You could add a SaveAllAsync() so you can test this only on this single controller for this specific issue, the rest of the calls leave them as they are, with SaveAll(). This would require to change to async only the method in this controller